# I want to add an App Drawer in my flutter app but outside of scaffold

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The problem is I'm adding an app drawer to my app where I've use custom appBar and it's a different class and I want to call an App Drawer from the CustomAppBar class where I don't have scaffold (it goes to white screen when I add scaffold).

I've tried multiple ways that i could think of to call it with onPressed attribute of my IconButton.

This is my main class

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              FirstHalf(),
              SizedBox(
                height: 45.0,
              ),
                   for (var foodItem in fooditemList.foodItems)
                   ItemContainer(foodItem: foodItem)
                 ],
              ),
            ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is where the CustomAppBar is called

```
class FirstHalf extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(35, 25, 0, 0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          CustomAppBar(),  //CustomAppBar
          SizedBox(
            height: 30.0,
          ),
          title(),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30.0,
          ),
          searchBar(),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30.0,
          ),
          categories(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

the code of this class isn't ended here but I think this much is enough to share rather than  sharing the entire code

and this is CustomAppBar class where I want to call app drawer

```
class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final CartListBLoc bloc = BlocProvider.getBloc<CartListBLoc>();
  CustomAppBar(); 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            onPressed: () {},//want to call app drawer here
          ),
          StreamBuilder(
            stream: bloc.listStream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              List<FoodItem> foodItems = snapshot.data;
              int length = foodItems != null ? foodItems.length : 0;
              return buildGestureDetector(length, context, foodItems);
            },
            initialData: <FoodItem>[],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
 }
```

Comment: Your `Home` class is not using `CustomAppBar `. Is `CustomAppBar` expected to be part of `Home` class?

Comment: I'm really sorry I made a mistake, I had to show one more class which uses customappbar as appbar, I'll edit the question as soon as I get back home.

Comment: the edit is done, I'm a beginner and even a little help will be appreciated, Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a way, you can make use of `GlobalKey` with `ScaffoldState`. There is a method `openDrawer()` on `ScaffoldState`.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>(); // Define key
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey, // pass scaffoldKey to Scaffold
      drawer: Drawer(), // your drawer implementation
      body: SafeArea(
        ....
              FirstHalf(scaffoldKey: scaffoldKey), // Pass scaffold key down the path.
        ...
       ....
}
```

```
class FirstHalf extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey;

  FirstHalf(this.scaffoldKey);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ....
    ....
    CustomAppBar(scaffoldKey), //CustomAppBar
    ....
  }
```

```
class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey;

  final CartListBLoc bloc = BlocProvider.getBloc<CartListBLoc>();
  CustomAppBar(this.scaffoldKey);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ....
    ....
    onPressed: () {
      this.scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer() // This opens drawer.
    },
    ....
}
```

As a general practice, I would normally try to avoid using CustomAppBar.

Hope this helps.